# MySql access with HTML 5 and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html

This is a noob question , but if I needed to make a basic form type page where the user can submit data( note for my previous questions, that was about very specific data sent from a  mobile app) . For this would I run HTML5 code inside of a php page ? , any guides on getting started would be great .

Comment: So much for summer of love, although I put a disclaimer saying its a noob question I get down voted and lose two rep ....

Comment: Don't take down votes personally, really.  (I know it's easy for a high-rep user to say that, but I'm serious.)  People vote however they want to vote.  Take it as an opportunity to try to improve the question.  Add context, add some code (even just pseudo code to express an idea), etc.  If they don't remove their down votes, that's more their problem than yours in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: as an aside, be VERY careful with HTML5. It's implementation is very spotty. It looks like you're just starting to learn, I'd recommend looking at the links below and focus on tried and true HTML for now. Later, you'll learn when and where to use HTML5

Comment: Yeah, the thing about this site is its populated by both hobbyist , like myself, and professionals who make a living off web design . Like i'm already happy with what i've been able to implement thus far ( google charts FTW!) and this community has been a great help .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More correctly stated, you would serve an HTML page using PHP, and process the resulting form submission with PHP.  It could be HTML5, or XHTML1.1 etc.

A good starting point is [PHP for the absolute beginner](http://devzone.zend.com/6/php-101-php-for-the-absolute-beginner/) from the [Zend Developer Zone](http://devzone.zend.com/).  This tutorial goes on to discuss database access and form processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can start from reading some tutorials, ex [link](http://bytes.com/topic/php/insights/664241-using-html-forms-pass-data-php)
Google knows a lot of them [google](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=php%20form%20send%20data)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you dont know how PHP+HTML works.

PHP is a Pre HTML Processor.

Using it on a Mobile or not will not make difference.
Note that HTML 5 is a "model" of HTML.
The php just pre process the data and transform it into HTML and output to your browser
So you can develop using it.

Like:

```
<?
echo '<br /> asd asd <p>MESSAGE FROM PHP';
?>
```

What you need to do is create a form in your html page and submit to a php page.

Like
HTML

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username" />
  <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

PROCESS.PHP

```
<?php

   $username=$_POST['username']; //now you have the username in a variable

   mysql_connect('ip', 'username', 'password');
   mysql_select_database("mydatabase");
   mysql_query("insert into users (username) values('".$username."')");
?>
```

So the php process the form and submit to the database

Comment: What I was saying is that my other questions are about data sent from a standalone app( actually coded with C# and Unity 3D) that runs on mobile . But this answer is golden , thank you

Comment: If you want to send data to a php page from unity you can see this topic: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/23884/how-to-post-and-get-on-a-https-web-page.html. You can send data as GET and use the http://www.page.com/page.php?username=theusername and get on the php side using $_GET or use the POST method and do the same way that is on the post